# Is there a way to use retrofit in a service (or something similar)?

Tags: android, android-service, retrofit

I rolled my own restful services and JSON parsing and am hoping to switch to Retrofit.  Currently my activity sends an intent to a service to fetch the necessary data.  The result is passed to a receiver which handles the parsing.  I'm not sure how to do this with Retrofit, since services can't return complex objects.  Of course I could convert my objects back to a string so they can be bundled up, but this defeats the entire point of using Retrofit with GSON.

Is there a clean way to do this?  I like how my current implementation kept my Activity clean from knowing about the end point and data parsing.

Thanks!

Comment: object can be parcelled and put into bundles and intent. So you can easily send complex objects back and forth between services and activities

Comment: Are the services in the same process as the app?

Comment: Yes, they're in the same process.  @Aegis: Doesn't this make parsing the data in the service pretty pointless?  Why spend the effort parsing the JSON if I'm going to turn around to parcel it up then unparcel?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [RoboSpice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice). Highly customisable and easy to use with Retrofit.